# Angular Routing - Direct path access not working from URL

Tags: angular-routing, angular8

I created and host [www.xinthose.com](http://www.xinthose.com).  [This is the source code for the website](https://github.com/xinthose/personal_website).  When you navigate to the website, it will take you to the path `/home`, but when you try to duplicate that tab or go directly to [www.xinthose.com/home](http://www.xinthose.com/home), I get a 404 error from HostGater (my website host).  This is the contents of `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent }   from './home/home.component';
import { BibleComponent }   from './bible/bible.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'bible', component: BibleComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?  Is it related to `pathMatch` at all?  Am I missing some [Route property](https://angular.io/api/router/Route)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me almost a year, but I figured out that you have to pay for `node.js` hosting, AWS elastic beanstalk is a good candidate for this.  Then you have to serve your static compiled website using something like `express.js`.  This is my working example `server.js`:

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const compression = require('compression');

// config
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app_folder = "./";
const options = {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  etag: false,
  extensions: ['html', 'js', 'scss', 'css'],
  index: false,
  maxAge: '1y',
  redirect: true,
}

// create app
const app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(app_folder, options));

// serve angular paths
app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(`/`, {root: app_folder});
});

// start listening
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Node Express server for " + app.name + " listening on http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

Then in `package.json` you have a start command the website host will run:

```
{
    "name": "xinthose.com",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "dependencies": {...},
    "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative solution, *May 2022*:**

This is probably a very late answer and I see that you have already solved your question. However, here is an alternative (free hosting but depending on the services you use it can be paid):

You can use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) to host your angular application for free. There is the possibility to also use your own domain if you don't want to use the default urls generated from Firebase. I had initially hosted my application elsewhere, which resulted in the same problem that you described above, however hosting the application using Firebase solved this issue for me.

You can implement firebase in your application simply from the Firebase documentation (link above) or a simpler solution is to implement it using [angular/angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) which is the official implementation of Firebase for Angular. Please install the library with `ng add @angular/fire` and follow the instructions given in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

This is not because of the web app route roles.

Angular applications have to become installed , and available so , angular router can be usable , so , when ever you try to access route like this 'domain/home' , you will get 404 error.

There is three solution that i know right now

## 1st 'best'

[Angular universal](https://universal.angular.io)

## 2nd

If your host is something like apache , that use php files, try to rewrite routes like this

search for rewrite urls for any other kind of host servers

- .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

## 3rd

Use [PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)

this one is awesome, but still , application have to be installed on user device , but after first launch , direct routes will work

Comment: Did not know that.  Thank you.  I will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file inside your root then add the following...Angular needs to send such request back to index.html

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

**Example web.config for IIS Hosting**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- handlers etc -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(^(?!.*\.[\d\w]+$).*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*\/api\/.*" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
``
```

Comment: thank you; yes, I know this now; You need URL rewrite rules for IIS hosting (I added an example to your answer).